# Pitch detection when successive notes are the same

Tags: audio, pitch

I want to program a microcontroller in C but I am asking about the theoretical aspect of it. I think I've got an idea what I am going to do but there is one thing I can't quite get. To begin with, I will use a guitar, so there is a 82Hz-987Hz range. So roughly, I'm going to low-pass the data on 1KHz, "window" them and apply FFT. Supposedly, I am going to have a good estimate.

Since highest frequency is ~1KHz, I decided my sample rate to be 2KHz (haven't tested yet if it works).

Suppose I have a 2 seconds track with 1 note each second. If the first note is C, my result would be 2000 C notes for the first second right? We can say that every time there is a note change, that's when you recognize a note, so if the second note is D, the program will acknowledge C, then D (and not 2000 times C and 2000 times D). The problem I see, is that if the second note is also C, how would I know that indeed there is a note hitting?

I believe I need an extra step to the process but I can't quite find what would that be. Might be that I have to go a different route though.. (if this is the case just mention the method, no need to elaborate on it and lose your time, I will read about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotpaw2's reply addressed the note boundary detection problem (envelope tracking is a solution, though they are more robust solutions, look for "onset detection"). A few more comments on your plan:

- Sampling your signal at 2kHz is going to cause more problems than it is going to solve. The signal from the guitar is not a pure sine wave, so there are harmonics above 1kHz that will be aliased if not filtered properly. This would require very steep anti-aliasing filters, with a very narrow transition band.
- You have not explained how you intend to compute pitch, but it is very unlikely that your pitch detection method is going to yield a result for every single input sample. More likely, you'll have to find a trade-off (for example through the choice of a FFT or autocorrelation size; or a bandpass filter Q factor) between how often you get a pitch estimate, and how accurate this estimate is.

Comment: This is a beginner's project so I am still grasping the basic concepts, that means some of my assumptions could be wrong.

1) About the sample rate, since I am already low-passing the sound at 1Khz it is going to eliminate the majority of harmonics over 1KHz. I just want to find the fundamental frequency and I don't need to reconstruct the signal so I assume that this sample rate won't be much of a problem.

Comment: 2) I was thinking that I can just find the peak frequency in each of my sample and then somehow I will find when a note is hitting. Granted, it isn't the best method but it's quite simple and the results will be terrible. I haven't tried programming it but playing with sounds and frequency domains on my PC, I can see with naked eye that most times the fundamental frequency is the one peaking.

Comment: Which filter do you use to limit the bandwidth to 1kHz? How do you determine "the peak frequency" from just one single sample?

Comment: I am thinking RC filter before ADC.
More like the peak frequency each time division. What would be a good time division length in order to apply the window function and FFT?

Comment: A simple RC filter will only attenuate harmonics, not eliminate them; so they will all be aliased in your 1kHz band and you'll get false readings. FFT is just not the right tool for note detection.

Comment: I guess you mean FFT _alone_ is not the right tool. Also, it's not a big problem to just change sampling rate, I can easily get it up to 16KHz if aliasing is indeed a problem. I think Harmonic Product Spectrum would do pretty good, if FFT is not enough. My question is how I would choose an appropriate time division length to apply a window function, then FFT, then HPS if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the envelope of a note will decay.  A new note pluck will start (add or replace) a new amplitude envelope with an attack transient.

So you might add envelope tracking to your spectral frequency analysis (which may or may not be appropriate for correct pitch estimation).